# Loop Collection copy and paste to separate sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to do a loop using a collection of data in a file called `BSC Working File`. The first field titled `Account Number` is pretty much what I'd be using.

I need to take the account numbers one at a time, copy them into a file `T24 SQL Query_Inputter_Authoriser_Branch Template` in the `Query` sheet into the first cell `A1`. This particular file is a SQL query sheet so when you input the account number into A1 the data for `Inputter` `Authorizer` and `Branch` is populated on "Sheet1" then I'd like to copy it back into the initial file `BSC Working File` then it would go to the next account number and so on until there is no more data.

[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Is the code in `BSC Working File` or somewhere else?

Comment: its within this file

Answer (score 0):

### A VBA Lookup in 2 Workbooks

- Carefully adjust the values in the constants section.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub UpdateBSC()
    
    ' Source
    Const swbPath As String _
        = "C:\Test\T24 SQL Query_Inputter_Authoriser_Branch Template.xlsx"
    Const slName As String = "Query"
    Const slAddress As String = "A1"
    Const svName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const svAddress As String = "A2:C2"
    ' Destination ("BSC Working File")
    Const dName As String = "Sheet1" ' ???
    Const dlColumn As String = "A"
    Const dvColumn As String = "G"
    Const dfRow As Long = 2
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    ' Source
    
    Dim swb As Workbook: Set swb = Workbooks.Open(swbPath)
    ' Lookup
    Dim slws As Worksheet: Set slws = swb.Worksheets(slName)
    Dim slCell As Range: Set slCell = slws.Range(slAddress)
    ' Value
    Dim svws As Worksheet: Set svws = swb.Worksheets(svName)
    Dim svrg As Range: Set svrg = svws.Range(svAddress)
    Dim cCount As Long: cCount = svrg.Columns.Count
    
    ' Destination
    
    ' If this workbook is a third workbook, supply a path and apply
    ' the same principle as for the source workbook.
    Dim dwb As Workbook: Set dwb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = dwb.Worksheets(dName)
    ' Lookup
    Dim dlRow As Long: dlRow = dws.Cells(dws.Rows.Count, dlColumn).End(xlUp).Row
    ' Value
    Dim dvrg As Range: Set dvrg = dws.Columns(dvColumn).Resize(, cCount)
    
    ' Copy
    
    Dim dr As Long
    For dr = dfRow To dlRow
        slCell.Value = dws.Cells(dr, dlColumn).Value
        ' If you need to refresh to trigger changes, this is the place to do it.
        dvrg.Rows(dr).Value = svrg.Value
    Next dr
    
    ' Finishing Touches
    
    swb.Close SaveChanges:=False
    ' dwb.Save
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    MsgBox "BSC updated.", vbInformation
    
End Sub
```